# Simple Ruby Regex Question

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a string in Ruby:

```
str = "<TAG1>Text 1<TAG1>Text 2"
```

I want to use gsub to get a string like this:

```
want = "<TAG2>Text 1</TAG2><TAG2>Text2</TAG2>"
```

In other words, I want to save everything in between a `<TAG1>` and EITHER: 1) the next occurrence of a "<", or 2) the end of the string.

The best regex i could come up with was:

```
regex = /<TAG1>(.*)(?:<|$)/
```

But the problem with this is that it'll just match the entire str, where what I want is both matches within str. (In other words, it seems like the end of string char ($) seems to have precedence over the "<" character--is there a way to flip it around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/<TAG1>([^<]*)/` will match that. If there's no `<` it'll go all the way to the end of the string. Otherwise it will stop when it hits a `<`. Your problem is that . matches `<` as well. An alternative way would be to do `/<TAG1>(.*?)(?:<|$)/`, which makes the `*` non-greedy.